# SEO publishing non-English articles

Tags: seo, ranking, language

I have a Slovak language websites and I would like to publish unique SEO articles, but all Slovak webs with PR2 and higher are paid for publishing.

In this case I would like to try publish them on non-Slovak webs, some English or use free blogs with PR4 and higher. Is this a good idea or not? Content and backlinks will be related to Slovak language and Slovak domains.

Will this help to rank linked keywords better or due to not publishing on Slovak site this won't work and will not have value?

Comment: I highly advise that you bring yourself up to date with modern day SEO. PageRank is dead, relevancy is key.

Comment: Simon is completely right! There is no possible way you can know a sites PR. This metric has not been available in years now. Anything that a site or toolbar is reporting would be completely false. As well, it is important that the content is the best it can be and adds unique value for the user. From my perspective, the content that performs best is content written naturally with some discipline in your natural language. Content written in a secondary language will not perform as well. You can translate into other languages of course. Just start where you live.

Comment: Be honest: slovak-language internet area isn't a place to earn any worth mentioning sum. Don't narrow yourself with slovak - publish in english and your audience will grow like mushrooms .

Comment: @Evgeniy So true.

Comment: Sorry but nobody gave me a relevant answer , check one more time my question please and if you have something to write, just then respond. I need to push slovak websites with their keywords in slovak google, so i need to publish articles in that language, i just asked if it will be valued for better ranking if i publish in non/slovak blogs and websites, thus anyway thx for your try

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is not a bad idea, but it will not help you so much with new visitors because they will go away instantly if they cant speak Slovak. But maybe it can help your PageRank. As Simon Hayter commented "page rank is dead, and relevance is key" so I don't think it is worth doing it if you are doing it just for PageRank.
If you will try it on Slovak websites with better PR it is worth it....

This is just my opinion, and it doesn't have to be true.

Answer (score 0):

## PR is not what it used to be

Talking about PR or other webs as the only factor to consider for publishing an article doesn't have sense in 2016.

> Relevancy is determined by over 200 factors, one of which is the PageRank for a given page.

## Missing the key topic: users

Will your unique SEO articles target Slovak users that also read English or not? Do you consider your articles will give a natural flow from the English speaking website that hosts your articles to the Slovak language websites? If that is the case then It *can* be a good idea.

I don't want to sound too pessimistic but I think you won't get clear answers, the question is too broad and is based in a misconception.